# What does the following function do? (scanl)

Tags: list, haskell

I really don't understand what does `scanl (\s f -> f s ) g` do in this example. What is `f`?

```
data Grid = Grid [Line]
data CellState = Dead | Alive deriving (Eq)
data Cell = Cell CellState Int deriving (Eq)
data Line = Line [Cell] Int deriving (Eq)

run :: Grid -> Int -> [Grid]
run g n = scanl (\s f -> f s) g $ replicate n playRound

playRound :: Grid -> Grid
```

Comment: `f` is the second parameter of the lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl):

> scanl is similar to foldl, but returns a list of successive reduced values from the left:
>
> ```
> scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
> ```
>
> Note that
>   `last (scanl f z xs) == foldl f z xs`.

So, `scanl (\s f -> f s ) g` behaves like this:

```
scanl (\s f -> f s) g [x1, x2, ...] == [g, x1 g, x2 (x1 g), ...]
```

Since `\s f -> f s` is an [anonymous function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function) which takes two arguments and applies the second to the first:

```
 λ> (\s f -> f s) 2 (+1)
 3
 λ> (\s f -> f s) "Hello" length
 5
```

Note that `\s f -> f s` could be written as `flip ($)`.

---

So, specifically:

```
run g n = scanl (\s f -> f s) g $ replicate n playRound
```

Could be seen as:

```
run g n = [g, playRound g, playRound (playRound g), ...] -- Repeated n times.
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the [documentation of **`scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) we see that:

> ```
> scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
> ```
>
> scanl is similar to foldl, but returns a list of successive reduced
>   values from the left:
>
> ```
> scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
> ```
>
> Note that
>
> ```
> last (scanl f z xs) == foldl f z xs.
> ```

So it starts with n initial value `z`, and each time it applies a function to `z` and the next element of the given list.

Here the initial value is `g`, and the list is `replicate n playRound` (which means a list of `n` items, each item is `playRound`). The function here takes the *accumulator* `s`, and an element of the list (here always `playRound`), and the outcome of `f s` (in this case `playRound s`), is the next item in the list.

So it will produce a list:

```
[g, playRound g, playRound (playRound g), ...]
```

and the list will contain `n+1` items.

Probably a more elegant approach should have been:

```
run :: Grid -> Int -> [Grid]
run g n = take (n+1) $ iterate playRound g
```